# some div backgrounds not showing

Tags: html, css, background-image

Trying to add a border to some divs but am having some trouble!  The left and right side aren't showing up for some reason.  Code is as follows, also on jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/3owmdzz4/

CSS:

```
*{
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
border : 0;
}
body{
    background-image: url('img/0x0E14.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    cursor: url('cursor.cur'), auto;
}
.blended_grid{
    display : table;
    width : 791px;
    overflow : auto;
    margin : 50px auto 0 auto;
}
.menu{
    background-image : url('img/menu.png');
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : 54px;
    width : 791px;
}
.left{
    background-image : url('img/bg-left.png');
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : auto;
    width : 77px;
}
.center{
    background-image : url('img/0x00C8.png');
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : auto;
    width : 637px;
}
.right{
    background-image : url('img/bg-right.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : auto;
    width : 77px;
}
.footer{
    background-image : url('img/footer.png');
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : 68px;
    width : 791px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Write some words to describe your html page">
</head>
<body>
<div class="blended_grid">
    <div class="menu">
    </div>
    <div class="left"><img src="img/dragon-left.png">
    </div>

    <div class="center">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    </div>

    <div class="right"><img src="img/dragon-right.png">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone please tell me what I did wrong?  Thanks!!

Comment: why fixed height?? if you will increase then its ok.

Comment: @Leothelion how do you mean?  I've tried adjusting the height properties but get the same result!

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/3owmdzz4/4/

Comment: @Leothelion thank you!!

Comment: @Leothelion actually- what if I need it to be taller than that? I tried height=100% but it disappeared again!

Comment: wait..give me 5 min plz

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your code and your requirement, i have done changes in css as well as in html too.

Please check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/3owmdzz4/5/)

I just used background on main container div `.foo` .

```
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/DKiJnsX.png') bottom left repeat-y, url('http://i.imgur.com/HInbtY0.png') bottom right repeat-y;
```

so if div's height will increase, both borders will also increase. Hope it will help. Let me know if you have any question. Thank you

Comment: Wow, thank you!  I originally tried to do it like you suggest here but couldn't, this is great!!

Comment: My pleasure that i helped you :)